# tcpdump to capture error IP Flags packets

Tags: fragment, tcpdump

I am using:

```
# tcpdump -i gphy -vv -B 28000 -s 120 -w log.pcap tcp portrange 10032-10001
```

to capture packets which I sent out from a host, and I notice all the packets with IP flags altered are missing, is there away to capture all packets even if IP flags is not correctly programmed ?

Answer (score 1):

This non deterministic behaviour could occur due to multiple potential reasons, such as incorrectly setting the 'Do Not Fragment' bit in IP flags, which may result in the packet being dropped. Perhaps you should ensure that you've correctly set the IP flags field to check whether the packet is being sent. If it is being sent (and not being dropped during transmission), with the given command you should be able to capture all packets (provided they match the filter).